# Detecting events in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe consisting of 0,1,-1's.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'indicator':[0, 0, 0, -1,0,0,1,0,-1,1,0,-1,0,1]})
```

and I wan't to find the indices of  every -1 and 1 such that the -1 is  followed by some or none zeros and a +1. For exapmle in the above example I want to get

```
[(3,6),(8,9),(11,13)]
```

Comment: Hi, this looks like a parsing problem for which regular expressions would be a very good solution(if you had a string). I'm afraid you will have to loop over the dataframe values and check the following values.

Answer (score 5):

```
s = pd.DataFrame({'indicator':[0, 0, 0, -1, 0,
                               0, 1, 0, -1, 1,
                               0, -1, 0, 1]}).squeeze()

# reduce it to non-zeros
s1 = s[s!=0]
# must be -1 and next one be 1, grab index
idx = s1.loc[(s1 == -1) & (s1 != s1.shift(-1))].index
# grab s1 index and next index
s2 = s1.index.to_series().shift(-1).loc[idx].astype(int)
# zip to get tuples
zip(s2.index, s2.values)

[(3, 6), (8, 9), (11, 13)]
```

Comment: Certainly a very general solution, containing a lot of pandas stuff I still want to learn :-)

Comment: I deleted my beautiful answer ;-( you were correct and the author has consecutive 1s and -1s in the data. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Ohumeronen It was a nice answer.  Hopefully you don't think I came off impolite.  I just wanted to point out what I saw.

Comment: I don't think you were impolite but I think during this conversation I learned a bit about generality and it's importance. So even though I was a little frustrated I think it was worth discussing.